# File I/O issue - conflicting while loops

Tags: c, io, while-loop, file-get-contents

```
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, f)) { 
            int len = strlen(line);
            if (length!=len-1){ 
                    fputs("max errorz\n", stderr); 
                    exit(1);
            }
            break;  

    }  

    while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
            putchar(c);
     }
```

I have a problem displaying all the contents in a text file. At the moment, the first while loop runs successfully, it checks the length of a file (characters), and if it matches the argument. I have finished this one, but for my 2nd loop after checking if the input matches the length of file , now i want to fully display the text file. BUT, it only displays 2/3 lines of the file. the first line looks like it was "taken" by the first loop.

Anyone know why this is?

I have tried putting the 2nd loop first, and it works (displays the full contents of the file).

Comment: Maybe this helps: use [`rewind(f);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/?kw=rewind) before the second loop to set the position inside the file back to the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the first loop reads from the file, it advances the read offset. After, all you'd expect this to work, right?

```
fgets(line1, sizeof line1, f);
fgets(line2, sizeof line2, f);
/* line1 and line2 now hold the first two lines */
```

So calling `getc` after `fgets` behaves the same way - it reads from where you left off.

Just move back to the beginning again between loops:

```
fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_SET);
```

or as pzaenger suggests, the equivalent

```
rewind(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `fgets` on FILE* f, f's position in the file moves forward so subsequent calls will not read the same data. When you go to use `getc` f points to where the first loop left it, in the middle of the file. You want to put `f` back to the beginning of the file. Try `rewind(f)` as @pzaenger suggests.

Answer (score 0):

After fetching some data from the file, file pointer moves some position forward from the starting position. if you want to set back the file pointer to starting position of the file you need to use `rewind()`.

```
 while (fgets(line, sizeof line, f)) { 
        int len = strlen(line);
        if (length!=len-1){ 
                fputs("max errorz\n", stderr); 
                exit(1);
        }
        break;  

}  
rewind(f); // fix

while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - You are not necessary reading the whole lenght of your file. Read the documentation:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

2 - Why putting a *break* into a while command without any *if* around? This means that your break is always hit and so it means that you don't need the while. See the same link as before.

3 - You print only part of the file because you've already read part of it using the while, you have to rewind your pointer as suggested by others. Again see
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/?kw=rewind